# is this a correct javascript code format?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add change the css of anything that matches `b-video > p` that has an `embed` element with JQuery but I'm having trouble.

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
$('div.b-video > p').has('embed').attr('style','display:block;');
```

Can anyone can help?
this is the full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.sb-video > p').has('iframe').attr('style','display:block;');
$('div.sb-video > p').has('embed').css('display','block');
$('div.b-video > p').has('embed').css('display','block'); 
$('div.b-video > p').has('iframe').attr('style','display:block;');
});
</script>
```

it works for iframe but it wont work for embed.

this is the embed HTML

```
<div class="b-video"><p>
<embed width="500" height="281" wmode="transparent" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://v.wordpress.com/hrPKeL5t">
</p>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Provide js fiddle of the html/js where this is not working.

Comment: Yes, the code is valid JavaScript and even valid jQuery. However this does not mean that it will work for your markup. Please provide the relevant HTML and a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: for formatting and code quality use JSLINT http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: @ Veseliq i've pasted the html

Comment: why are you trying to add display:block to a `<p>` tag which is already a block tag ? Perhaps you're asking the wrong question. What effect are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't. In any case that's jQuery, not plain JavaScript

And it should be

```
$('div.b-video > p').has('embed').css('display','block');
```

Just see the documentation ( http://api.jquery.com/has/ ), it has the following example:

```
$('li').has('ul').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: It's tagged as javascript/jquery, so probably your answer is useless.

Comment: @user1564354 If you are trying to add `display:block` because you want it to be `width:100%` (just a guess), you could use `$('div.b-video > p > embed').css('width','100%')`